# Show that $\lim \frac1{n^2 +1} =0$

Tags: real-analysis

I am not very familiar to epsilon... But this question belongs to my Sallybus and I want to understand it with the help of epsilon definition.. Kindly help me to solve it

Comment: Ok, if you aren't comfortable with epsilon-delta proofs, first, write down the definition of a limit in terms of epsilon delta, then apply the conditions of the definition. Edit your work in so we can see where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 2):

In the first place, it is worth to emphasize the definition of convergence of sequences.

Let $x_{n}\in X$, where $(X,d)$ is a metric space. We say that $x_{n}$ converges to $x_{0}\in X$ iff
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N})\,\,\text{s.t.}\,\,(n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d(x_{n},x_{0}) < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

At the present case, $(X,d) = (\mathbb{R},d)$, $x_{n} = (n^{2}+1)^{-1}$ and $x_{0} = 0$, where $d(x,y) = |x - y|$.

Having said that, we can proceed.

To begin with, I would start with noticing that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n^{2}+1} < \frac{1}{n^{2}} < \varepsilon \Rightarrow n > \frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}
\end{align*}

Thus, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds a natural number $n_{\varepsilon} = \Bigl\lceil\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\Bigr\rceil$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n^{2}+1} < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be the goal to approach. We want to find an integer $N>0$ such that whenever $n > N$, we have $\frac{1}{n^2+1} < \varepsilon$. As we know $\frac{1}{n^2+1} < \frac{1}{n}$, let's pick $N$ be the smallest integer greater than $1/\varepsilon$. Then whenever $n>N$, we have $n>N\geq1/\varepsilon$ and $\frac{1}{n^2+1} < \frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$. That's exactly what we want to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Option:

Let $n \ge1;$

$\dfrac{1}{n^2+1} \le\dfrac{1}{n^2} \le \dfrac{1}{n};$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Archimedian principle:

There exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s. t.

$n_0 >1/\epsilon;$

For $n\ge n_0:$

$\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}\le \dfrac{1}{n}<\dfrac{1}{n_0} <\epsilon. $